# Getting undefined error trying to access nested object field using Array.prototype.filter

Tags: javascript

I'm using the query below to get all forms from a model;

```
query = await Form.find({}).populate('assigned_to');
```

the query result is as below;

```
[{
        **
        Some Other Fields **
        assigned_to: {
            links: [Array],
            _id: 5 d7a903d8b8f3e0ced2dd308,
            name: 'Test E 2',
            email: 'te2@somedomain.com',
            school: 5 d79e99b4d4df989ea771525,
            department: 5 d79e99b4d4df989ea771526,
            role: 'some_role',
            __v: 0
        },
    }, 
      **
    OTHER OBJECT 
      **
]
```

Running an Array.prototype.filter;

```
waiting = query.filter(form =>
form.assigned_to._id == req.user._id);
```

Trying to accessing the property `_id` of the nested object `assigned_to` returns an error of;

> Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

I understand the nature of the error being that not all forms have an `assigned_to` nested object at the same time which would result in that error because running a filter on the form solely which has that nested objects passes.

How do I improve this filter to cater for the possibility that not all forms have assigned_to nested object?

**EDIT:** I didn't originally indicate that it query was an array of objects for brevity.

Comment: `query` is an object. There is no object `filter` method.

Comment: The `query` you've shown doesn't appear to be an array. Did you mean that the array elements (`form`) look like this? And did you make sure that *all of them* do have an `assigned_to` object associated with them?

Comment: I didn't originally indicate that it query was an array of objects since I said I was using Array.prototype.filter, but I've edited the query result to indicate that

Comment: The error implies that some of the results don't have an `assigned_to` property.

Comment: Are there supposed to be quotes around the `_id` value?

Comment: Also `school` and `department`?

Comment: @Barmar Like you, I ,mentioned in my description that not all objects in the array have an `assigned_to`  property. No quotes are needed around `_id` because it's a property. `school` and `department` are also fine. Check my accepted answer below. It's exactly what I was looking for. Some condition in the filter.

Comment: Why aren't quotes needed? They look like strings, they need quotes to delimit them. So it should be `_id: "5 d7a903d8b8f3e0ced2dd308",`

Comment: @Barmar The reason why the quotes aren't necessary is because I'm getting that information from a MongoDB collection. its an ObjectID which refers to a model. if it's quoted, it wouldn't be an ObjectID anymore but rather a String which isn't the type. This is the exact line from the database which is in it's complete form as opposed to the result from the query; `"_id" : ObjectId("5d8e15c089a4b210c228417d")`. Hope this help clear this up.

Comment: That wasn't clear, it looked like you were just writing an ordinary JavaScript object literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for your question "**How do I improve this filter to cater for the possibility that not forms have assigned_to nested object?**". Make sure query returns an array.

This will make sure if key "assigned_to" is present. You could use filter method like :-

```
arr.filter(elem => (elem.assigned_to && elem.assigned_to._id &&
elem.assigned_to._id === req.user._id));
```

Another way

```
arr.filter(elem => {
  if(elem.assigned_to && elem.assigned_to._id) {
    if (elem.assigned_to._id === req.user._id) {
      return elem;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/GrimQueasyFtpclient. Running example in case needed. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you much. I was trying a conditional like you but I wasn't including the if, only `(condition) return x`.